# LWC : onchange Handler not getting fired when @track attribute is changed

Tags: lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom, lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

I have two lightning input in a simple LWC component having respective onchange handlers and being @tracked with respective attributes. Second onchange handler is getting fired when I update second @track attibute from onchange handler of first input. Why?

HTML Code:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-input type="text" value={accountName} label="Enter Account Name" onchange={handleAccountNameChange}></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input type="text" value={contactName} label="Enter Contact Name" onchange={handleContactNameChange}></lightning-input>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS Code :

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
export default class LdsExample1 extends LightningElement {
    @track accountName;
    @track contactName;
    handleAccountNameChange(event){
        console.log('Account Name changed');
        this.contactName = 'N/A';
    }
    handleContactNameChange(event){
        console.log('Contact Name Changed');
    }
}
```

Here, When I am changing Account Name from UI, I am updating Contact Name to 'N/A' from JS, which is getting reflected in UI but why "handleContactNameChange" is not getting fired here?

Please help me in this. Can I add onhandle event listener on @track attribute in JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML specifies that onchange handlers only fire for UI (user) updates, not by JavaScript. This isn't a framework limitation or anything, just standard, default behavior of the standards. This prevents (trivially) wiring up infinite recursion problems. If you really want to respond to *any* change, use a setter:

```
_contactName;
get contactName() {
  return _contactName;
}
set contactName(value) {
  this._contactName = value;
  console.log('responding to change in attribute')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[You no longer need the track decorator](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_track.htm&type=5&release=224) for your property to be reactive, regardless of if you are using it or not, your code should work:

tempalte:

```
<template>
    <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter Account Name" onchange={handleChange} value={account}></lightning-input>
</template>
```

JS file:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

```
export default class Input extends LightningElement {
    account = "account name";
    handleChange(event){
        console.log(event.detail.value)
    }
}
```

I did a quick copy paste, and the handle method fires on change of the input field value.

Comment: Hello, Kindly go through my ques, I am aware about @track changes in Spring 20 release. However, My question is regarding 2 way binding. Why event handler is not getting calling when track property is updated in JS.